# How to remove dynamically generated checkboxes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, pyqt, pyqt5

So I've got a pyqt5 GUI that generates checkboxes based on the titles of JSON files that are saved in a directory. My next step is making it so that when the users checks a box, it deletes the checkbox, and then the JSON file.

Currently I generate the checkboxes as follows:

```
        for x in self.list:
            layout.addWidget(QCheckBox(x),row,0)
            row+=1
```

Since I have not assigned each checkbox to an object, how would I go about checking the state of each box, and then assigning it an action?

Since I'm learning to discuss what I was thinking:

I was hoping I could use Signals to detect when a signal is transmitted from the overall widget, and then slot that with a function that deletes any file in the directory sharing the name of the object that generated the signal.

Is there a better approach to generate the checkboxes as well?

Comment: Indeed. Just create a list as instance attribute, like `self.checkboxes = []`, and then `checkBox = QCheckBox(x); self.checkboxes.append(checkBox)`.

Comment: @musicamante Hmm, this confuses me a little to be honest ,  so in your example checkboxes is the list of labels I generate from the json file names,  but what confuses me is why we append checkBox to checkboxes? isn't checkBox in your example the object of the checkboxes in pyqt?

Comment: No. `checkboxes` is an empty list to which you add all the check boxes whenever you create them. If you want to connect the file names, create a dictionary that has the file names as keys and the checkbox instances as values (and always remember to delete the key/value pair when you remove the checkbox!). That said, it all depends on the *logic* of your program. For instance, if you have a long list of files, you might prefer to use a model-view pattern: for an usage like this, a QListWidget can be a better choice.

Comment: Oh wait I understand! we're appending a new list of objects, with those objects being the checkbox object! perfect! I think I'm good thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To store the widget so later you can access them create some container, `List` will do perfectly:

```
self.checkboxes = []
...
checkbox = QCheckBox("Iam checkbox number: {}".format(len(self.checkboxes))) #Create checkbox
 
self.vbox.addWidget(checkbox) #Add it to layout
self.checkboxes.append(checkbox) #Store it for later use in List
```

For deleting them you can use the `.deleteAfter()` method:

```
self.checkboxes[-1].deleteLater() #[-1] gives us the last element and .deleteLater() gets rid of the widget GUI wise.
self.checkboxes.pop() #Then we just remove the last element from the list so it doesn't take space
```

---

This is the whole working example:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton, QCheckBox, QVBoxLayout

class App(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.width = 320
        self.height = 200
        self.initUI()
    
    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle("My app")
        
        self.vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        self.vbox.addStretch(1)

        cr_button = QPushButton('Press to add widgets')
        cr_button.clicked.connect(self.create)

        del_button = QPushButton('Press to delete widgets')
        del_button.clicked.connect(self.delete)

        self.vbox.addWidget(cr_button)
        self.vbox.addWidget(del_button)

        self.checkboxes = []

        self.setLayout(self.vbox)
        self.show()

    def create(self):
        checkbox = QCheckBox("Iam checkbox number: {}".format(len(self.checkboxes)))

        self.vbox.addWidget(checkbox)

        self.checkboxes.append(checkbox)
        self.show()

    def delete(self):
        self.checkboxes[-1].deleteLater()
        self.checkboxes.pop()
        self.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = App()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```